# Error closing R commander when package rgl is loaded

Tags: r, libraries, r-commander

```
library(ca)
# Loading required package: rgl
library(Rcmdr)
# R Commander starts

# When trying to close R Commander window
Error in unloadNamespace("rgl") : name space 'rgl' is still used by: 'ca'
```

What is the suggested way to close R Commander in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`unloadNamespace('ca')`

then close the 'Rcmdr' window.

You'll need to reattach the 'ca' package if you still need to use it.

Comment: Error in closeCommander(ask.save = getRcmdr("ask.on.exit")) : 
  could not find function "rgl.quit"

Comment: It's not clear how, from the steps you've outlined above, but the 'rgl'
package has been detached while its namespace remains. 'Rcmdr' checks this before it exits and will unsuccessfully try to quit 'rgl' for you. Anyway, now you should try:

`unloadNamespace('rgl')`

Now close 'Rcmdr'.